# Ktor unable to receive POST body on Server

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have the following Server and Client code:

Server:

```
fun Application.main() {
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CallLogging)
    install(Routing) {
        post("/") {
            val requestBody = call.receiveText()
            println("Received $requestBody")
            call.respond("Hello from server - received $requestBody")
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, 8080) {
        main()
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

Client:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    HttpClient(CIO).use {
        val postResult = it.post<String>("http://localhost:8080/") {
            body = "Client Hello"
        }
        println(postResult)
    }
}
```

So, the client just sends "Client Hello" to the server in the POST-body, and the Server responds to that.
But I didn't see the content of the body on the server-side. What am I doing wrong?

The `call.receiveText()` is always empty.

Comment: Which version of ktor are you using? It seems that `0.9.2-alpha-6` doesn't have this problem. `0.9.2` will be released soon.

Comment: I'm using 0.9.1 (so the latest released version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue fixed in recent alphas(>= `0.9.2-alpha-5`) and would appear in next `0.9.2` release soon.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what "soon" means?

Comment: It seems you are a new Dev @Jebrains. Glad to give you your first reputation points. Welcome on Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

And if you have parameters in your body request, try it:

```
val requestBody = call.receiveParameters()
val value = requestBody["key_name"]
```